# Returning multiple records using Recordset MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

I have an MS Access form that has a combo box (which acts as a primary key) called `cboProjectID`. I am trying to create the form in a way so that once a selection is made in the `cboProjectID` combo box, it triggers another combo box called `cboErrCod1` to display error codes based on those available to the project_id selected in the `cboProjectID` combo box.

Only certain Error Codes are available to certain Project ID's and those are defined in another table. However, i have created a query called `HDR_ERRCODES` that relates `Project_ID`, `Project_Code` and the possible `Error_Reason_Code` 's available to a specific `project_Id`.

For example, a project code (which is selected from the cboProjectID combo box) could look something like these: "FI-01-05", "FI-01-01", "SY-02-02" etc). Once selected, the `Project_ID` is stored in the table `Project_DTA_REV_T` (this is the table that the form stores its information) and the `Project_ID` is simply a next up number (1,2,3,4 etc. etc.).

I understand that you need to use a Recordset to return multiple values when doing VBA code. This is the code I have started off with but it doesnt seem to be working in the "on change" command for the cboProjectID combo box field:

```
Private Sub cboProjectID_Change()

Dim VarComboKey As Integer

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim Err1 As DAO.Recordset

VarComboKey = Me.cboProjectID.Value

Set dbs = CurrentDb

Set Err1 = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [Error_Reason_Code] FROM [HDR_ErrCodes] WHERE [project_ID] = " & VarComboKey)

Do While Not Err1.EOF
   Me!cboErrCod1 = Me!cboErrCod1 & Err1!Error_reason_code & " "
   Err1.MoveNext
Loop

Err1.Close
Set Err1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am no VBA expert and have been trying to follow the coding methodology i have read on this website for Recordset's. Access is displaying every type of `Error_Reason_Code`, not the specific `Error_Reason_Code` 's pertaining to the project ID selected in the `cboProjectID` combo box.

Can someone point me in the right direction in getting this code to display on the `Error_Reason_Code` 's in the cboErrCod1 combo box, only pertaining to the `Project_ID` selected in the `cboProjectID` combo box??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the list of items displayed in a combo box you need to modify its `Row Source`. There are 3 options for the `Row Source Type`: `Table/Query`, `Value List` and `Field List`.

`Value list` will take a semi colon separated list of values and display them for selection.  For example if you entered a `Row Source` of "Cat;Dog;Mouse" you would get the following when selecting your drop down.

`cat`

`dog`

`mouse`

`Field List` will display the field names of whatever query or table you select as the row source.

`Table Query` is what you want.  This will populate the combo box with the values from the table or query you provide. What you are doing with your code now and the line `Me!cboErrCod1 = Me!cboErrCod1 & Err1!Error_reason_code & " "` is changing the currently displayed value in the Combo Box but not affecting the values that will be available when you expand it.  To do this you have to change the `Row Source` of your combo box with the query that you have already created.

`Me!cboErrCod1.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Error_Reason_Code] FROM [HDR_ErrCodes] WHERE [project_ID] = " & VarComboKey`

So your method would change to be what is below since you do not need to modify a record set.

```
Private Sub cboProjectID_Change()
    Dim VarComboKey As Integer

    VarComboKey = Me.cboProjectID.Value

    Me!cboErrCod1.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Error_Reason_Code] FROM [HDR_ErrCodes] WHERE [project_ID] = " & VarComboKey
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**  I have tried to duplicate your setup to see why the results would return nothing.  Please correct this if I have made any errors in my assumptions.

I made a form with a combo called `cboProjectID` that has a source that gets all of the project IDs from the project table(Select * from Projects;) and displays the Project Code in the drop down.  I made another one called `cboErrCod1`.

I made two tables one called `Projects` and the other called `ErrorCodes` with the following set ups based on your description.

```
Projects                          HDR_ErrCodes
ProjectID    ProjectCode(text)    Error_Reason_Code(text)    project_ID(integer)
1            FI-01-05             Failure                    1
2            FI-01-01             Testing                    1
3            SY-02-02             Manual                     1
4            SY-01-01             Failure                    2
5            SY-01-02
```

With the above set up and the on change event my combo box cboErrCod1 gets populated with the correct error codes.  Is there something wrong with that setup?

Comment: could you tell me how to modify the code above with what i originally had? i dont quite understand....

Comment: Sorry about that.  I have edited my answer and hopefully it is a little clearer.

Comment: the code that you provided above returns blank results in the cboErrCod1 combo box...would you know why this would be happening?

Comment: without some sort of "if" statement wouldnt the code NOT return multiple values? the code above seems like it would return 1 value and not multiple values?

Comment: do you have any idea why the combo boxes are coming up null?

Comment: @JT2013 I have updated my answer with some assumptions about your setup and my results.  Could you correct anything that is wrong so that I may assist further?

Comment: Hey @Zaider please have a look. You are correct in your assumptions

Comment: would you have to declare `cboErrCod1` as a variable first?

Comment: You would not declare it as a variable since it is the name of your combo box.